# AWS RDS Postgres replication to GCP cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql

I want to setup replication between AWS RDS and GCP for postgresql. I found documentation for MYSQL but i am not able to get for postgres.

is there any option to setup replication without any external tools?

Comment: i found somewhere that using repmgr we can setup replication in postgres.
but i am not sure how to use it with RDS & GCP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature it’s only [available for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/external-server) at the moment and there is no official support for replication between AWS RDS and GCP using PostgreSQL in Cloud SQL. However, please note that this may change in the future, and you are able to create a feature request about this using the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0).

Comment: This seems to no longer be true! https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/configure-source-database supports Postgres on RDS and Aurora. Haven't tried it though!